# How to delete Read the Docs account (readthedocs.org)

Tags: read-the-docs

A while ago I signed up for [Read the Docs](https://readthedocs.org/) but I now no longer wish to use the service.

On my settings page, there seems to be no 'delete account' option and I cannot find anything in the [documentation](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

Is there a way to delete my [RTD](https://readthedocs.org/) account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just adding an update for anyone trying to solve it: there is now an option to do so. Log in, go to https://readthedocs.org/accounts/delete/, enter your username and you can delete your account.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, there seems to be no way to do this yourself.

There's an issue in the GitHub issue tracker about this, because others alredy had the same problem:
[How to delete account on readthedocs.org?](https://github.com/rtfd/readthedocs.org/issues/292)
The issue is full of "please delete my account" comments, and at least in the beginning, those accounts were actually deleted by hand. I think this is your best chance at the moment.

But they intend to make deleting accounts possible in the future.
Eric Holscher *(one of the people behind Read the Docs)* [commented](https://github.com/rtfd/readthedocs.org/issues/292#issuecomment-36012648):

> We aren't an evil corporation
>   that won't let you delete your accounts on purpose, just a lazy open source
>   project that hasn't implemented the feature yet :)